# Getting into phd

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm from India and needed some suggestions for PhD admissions . I have completed my undergraduate this year with physics as my major. I have 2 gap years after my high school .  How much does gap years affect PhD interviews? I have around 8.6 GPA in my undergrad on scale of 10 . If I maintain GPA above 8 and do some projects in master's . Will it be enough to get through? Or year gaps would be problem in interviews? As i will have overall 3 gap years .

Comment: Are you applying to Indian PhD programs?

Comment: We can't really do individualized answers to admissions questions, you can see general information at a canonical post here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/63475 otherwise you'll have to distill down to one very specific aspect of admissions rather than a general blueprint for you.

Comment: I have edited my query . Its related to affect of gap years in PhD interviews.

Comment: I will prefer US but will apply for Indian programs too .

Comment: There are a lot more gap year questions and answers here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=gap+year

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl for guidance on how PhD admissions are evaluated in the US.

Comment: thanks for the links .